# Key binding for changing eclipse tab traversal

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

When using eclipse, I often use the find/replace tool without touching the mouse. I'll press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, type the text I want to find, press tab, type the replacement text, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> 3 times, to bring focus to the "replace all" button, then I press <kbd>Space</kbd> to perform the action and <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close the window.

Today, I tried this and tab will only switch between the "find" text box and the "replace with" text box, meaning I have to go to my mouse to perform the "replace all" action, which takes forever (comparatively). I have had this problem before, and thought I recalled a key binding that changes the focus traversal policy for eclipse, but I cant seem to find it now. Googling has turned up nothing, but I don’t think I am searching for the right terms. I don’t think this is OS related, but I am on a Mac.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this. It was OS related- Mac has a setting to allow tab navigation through buttons.
System Preferences-> keyboard, at the bottom select "all controls"